# How to keep the height of an outer div equal to the inner div?

Tags: html, css

I have an inner div used for overlay, set to a min-height property. When the height of the overlay changes, the height of the outer div will not be affected.

```css
#outer {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
}
#inner {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id = "outer">
    <div id = "inner">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update:**

The problem seems to be with the absolute positioning. What other ways to do an overlay while keeping the outer div's height equal to it?

Comment: Please include your actual code; enough to replicate the issue ... The actual situation you describe isn't the default behavior of elements, you maybe have some absolute position or fixed dimensions how can we know ?

Comment: Please can you create a [MCVE] as we cannot help without code

Comment: I added an example, check now.

Comment: you can't do that with an absolutely positioned child element - the absolutely positioned elements size cannot have any influence on the parent.

Comment: @Johannes 
Yes that's what I have discovered. Could you please provide a solution? Thanks.

Comment: As I wrote, there is no solution for this particular situation. Depending on what you really want to do with it (which is not clear from the quetsion) you have to find another way to deal with it, without using an absolutely positioned child element.

Comment: see my answer with an alternative solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in my comments, there's no way if you use absolute position. But if you change the code as follows, it works (still depending on the actual situation):

```css
#outer {
  width: 70px;
  min-height: 70px;
  background-color: #000;
}
#inner {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id = "outer">
    <div id = "inner">
      <br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works for me, I did need an alternative solution. Thank you!